# How to run ionic app on simulator?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have tried to run the application on emulator using:

```
ionic emulate ios
```

But the in the simulator when I open the app it only shows a blank screen, though the logs show that the build was fine.

I am using **Mac OS X Sierra** and the following:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.3.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command that worked for me was:

```
ionic state reset
```